# yii cgridview export into excel not working on pagination

Tags: excel, yii, pagination, export-to-csv

my code export into excel works fine, 1 to 10 rows export if I filters rows that my code export filtered rows as my criteria. If I click to next page e.g 11 to 20 and then click on export button, export only first page 1 to 10 rows.

in my admin view export button code:

```
<div id='menub'><?php    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
                   'encodeLabel'=>false,
                   'htmlOptions'=>array(
                       'class'=>'actions'),
                       'items'=>array(
                                   array(
                                       'label'=>'<img align="absmiddle" alt = "'.Yii::t('internationalization','Export'). '" src = "'.Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/export.jpg" />',
                                       //'label'=>'Export',
                                       'url'=>array('expenses/excel'),
                                    ),
                                    ),

            ));
```

above link call to excel method in expenses controller.
code in my controller:

```
    public function actionExcel() {

            $issueDataProvider = $_SESSION['report-excel'];
        $i = 0;
        $data = array();
        //fix column header. 
        //Could have used something like this - $data[]=array_keys($issueDataProvider->data[0]->attributes);. 
        //But that would return all attributes which i do not want
        //$data[]=array_keys($issueDataProvider->data[0]->attributes);
        $data[$i]['expenses_type_id'] = 'Type';
        $data[$i]['amount'] = 'Amount';
        $data[$i]['exp_date'] = 'Date';
        $data[$i]['description'] = 'Description';
        $i++;

        //populate data array with the required data elements
        foreach($issueDataProvider->data as $issue)
        {
            $data[$i]['expenses_type_id'] = $issue->expensesType->name;
            $data[$i]['amount'] = $issue['amount'];
            $data[$i]['exp_date'] = $issue['exp_date'];
            $data[$i]['description'] = $issue['description'];
            $i++;
        }
Yii::import('application.extensions.phpexcel.JPhpExcel');
        $xls = new JPhpExcel('UTF-8', false, 'test');
        $xls->addArray($data);
        $xls->generateXML('test_file');
}
```

I save data in

> $_SESSION['report-excel']

and in my Model:

```
public function getSearchCriteria()
        {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        if(!empty($this->from_date) && empty($this->to_date))
        {
            $criteria->condition = "exp_date >= '$this->from_date'";  // date is database date column field
        }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && empty($this->from_date))
        {
            $criteria->condition = "exp_date <= '$this->to_date'";
        }elseif(!empty($this->to_date) && !empty($this->from_date))
        {
            $criteria->condition = "exp_date  >= '$this->from_date' and exp_date <= '$this->to_date'";
        }

        $criteria->with = 'expensesType';
        $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN expenses_type p ON t.expenses_type_id = p.id'; 
        //s$criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
        $criteria->compare('p.name',$this->expenses_type_id,true);
        $criteria->compare('amount',$this->amount,true);
        $criteria->compare('exp_date',$this->exp_date,true);
        $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);
        $criteria->order ='exp_date DESC';

    return $criteria;
    }


    public function search()
    {
        // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.
$data = new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
                        'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',                                           
                                Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),),
                                'criteria'=>$this->getSearchCriteria(),


    ));

                     $_SESSION['report-excel']=$data;
         return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria'=>$this->getSearchCriteria(),
    ));
```

every thing is works fine but on pagination.
kindly help.

Comment: When you say "every thing is works fine but on pagination", does it mean that the export doesn't work on paged data-sets?

Comment: @ragingprodigly exactly right export doesn't work on paged sets, export first page data 1 to 10 and second page too

Answer (score 0):

CActiveDataProvider holds a set of items(all).So when you call actionExcel() the $page param is lost. So when you do actionAdmin() in your controller or search() in your model save your $_GET['page'] to an other session value. then set it when you do actionExcel().

```
$_GET['page'] = $_SESSION['your_session_page_value'];
```

Hope this helps

Best Regards

Comment: @Janz thanks for reply, I am newbie totally confused, can you give example.